# Proof clarification - If $ab = 0$ then $a = 0$ or $b =0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, real-numbers

I came across a proof for the following theorem in Apostol Calculus 1. My question is regarding (1) in the proof, why is this part necessary? I don't see why you can't begin with (2)

**Theorem 1.11**

If $ab = 0$ then $a = 0$ or $b=0$

**Proof**

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $ab =0$

Then, if $a \neq 0$ we know there exists $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a * a^{-1} = 1$

Thus,
$$\begin{align}
ab = 0 &\implies a^{-1}(ab) = a^{-1} \cdot 0 = 0\tag{1}\label{1} \\
\end{align}$$
But,

$$\begin{align}
a^{-1}(ab) = 0 &\implies (a^{-1}a)b = 0\tag{2}\\
&\implies 1\cdot b = 0\tag{3}\\
&\implies b = 0 \tag{4} 
\end{align}$$

Comment: Line (2) uses the associativity of multiplication of the real numbers, that is, for any real numbers $a, b, c$ then $a(bc) = (ab)c$. The reason you can't start with (2) is because when you multiply $a^{-1}$ to both sides of $ab = 0$ then you are implicitly multiplying $a^{-1}$ to $ab$ and so you must use associativity at some point.

Comment: ah ok, is it because line two doesn't show $a^{-1}(ab) = a^{-1} \cdot 0 \implies a^{-1}(ab) = 0$ (using $0 \cdot a = a \cdot 0 = 0$ which was proved as theorem 1.6 in the chapter)

Comment: and then associativity to get $(a^{-1} a)b = 0$

Comment: Yep, you can see it as combining it with transitivity of equality in one line

Answer (score 2):

Looks a bit weird. If $a\ne 0$, then $a$ is invertible and so
$$b = 1b = (a^{-1}a)b = a^{-1}(ab) = a^{-1}0 = 0.$$
In the last step, $b0=0$, I used the fact that $0$ is absorbing.

In the general case, if you have a ring $R$ and a unit $a\in R$, then the above proof shows that units are not zero divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $ab=0$ and $a\neq 0$. Then $a^{-1}(ab)=(a^{-1}a)b=b=0$